# How create object only once and use it in code?

Tags: android

What i'm trying to do :

```
Item(String name, int price, int owned){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.owned = owned;
}
```

Shop Activity:

```
public class ShopActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<AbstractItem> items = new ArrayList<AbstractItem>();
    private Game game;
    private BuySell buySell;

    Item item1 = new Item("Item1", 10, 0);
    Item item2 = new Item("Item2", 5, 0);
    Item item3 = new Item("Item3", 7, 0);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop);

        game = (Game) SingletonManager.getInstance().getClassReference(Game.class);

        items.add(item1);
        items.add(item2);
        items.add(item3);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.shopList);
        final ItemsAdapter adapter = new ItemsAdapter (this, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                AbstractItem selectedItem = items.get(position);
                buySell.buy(selectedItem, game);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And now my question. Every time i go in ShopActivity it creates new Object. I can buy, let's say 30pcs of Item1, go back to menu and to Shop again, and i get object with 0 owned. What should i do with those object to have only one of each? If anyone understand and can help, big thanks ;)

Comment: `go back to menu`. Does that mean that you close your activity? `and to Shop again`. It more looks that you do not return to your former activity but to a new one. So onCreate() is called.

Comment: Sorry for that english. Go back to menu means close this Activity, but not app.  "It more looks that you do not return to your former activity but to a new one". I think so. What i can do about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add dependency
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

Then use this to save and retrieve items.

```
public class Temp {

    private class Item {
        public Item(String name, int price, int owned) {

        }
    }

    private class ItemHolder {
        private ArrayList<Item> items;

        public ItemHolder(ArrayList<Item> items) {
            this.items = items;
        }

        public ArrayList<Item> getItems() {
            return items;
        }
    }

    public void yourMethod() {
        Context c = null;
        Item myItem1 = new Item("name", 0, 1);
        Item myItem2 = new Item("name", 0, 1);
        Item myItem3 = new Item("name", 0, 1);

        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(myItem1);
        items.add(myItem2);
        items.add(myItem3);

        //save your items
        savePersistent(new ItemHolder(items), c);

        //retrieve them anywhere
        ItemHolder savedItems = getPersistentData(c);

    }

    private void savePersistent(ItemHolder holder, Context ctx) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(holder);
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("key", jsonString);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private ItemHolder getPersistentData(Context ctx) {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        String jsonString = pref.getString("key", null);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ItemHolder obj = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ItemHolder.class);
        return obj;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Helps me A LOT ;) Beer for u!

Answer (score 0):

There are many options :

1. You can create static objects : have its own disadvantages.
2. Put your purchased items in shared preferences and recreate cart
   in onResume method of activity.
3. Store your cart in local database.

Comment: Can u give me some example what exactly should i do with this code to make it work? Where should i create those static object? Same place i do it now?

Comment: You can store your objects in shared preferences. Create an arrayList of objects Item. Create 2 functions : 1) to store this array list convert it to json 2) to get it back convert json to arrayList. Then you will be able to store your cart and show the arraylist to user by putting it into adapter.